# Why is the word “so” in the line, “To a ill-informed person I would have so answer yes,” shown in Italic to stress the word?

Tags: meaning, grammar, parts-of-speech

I am interested in the word, “so” in the following sentence in Jeffery Archer’s novel, “The Prodigal Daughter.”

Florentina Kane who is the chairman of an international hotel empire she succeeded from her father, and stood as a candidate for the Congresswoman for Illinoi State in late 1960s is asked question by a journalist at the press conference:

> “Do you consider it a disadvantage to be a woman when seeking public
> office?”
>
> ( She answered:)
>
> “Perhaps to a limited or ill-informed person **I would have *so*
> answer yes**, but not with any intelligent voter who puts the issues
> before outdated predudices. Which of you if involved in a traffic
> accident on the way home today would think twice if the first doctor
> on the scene turned out to be a woman?- The Prodigal Daughter(Published by St. Martin's Press) P.293.

*Naturally* I  read the bold line as “I would have **to** answer yes,” as most of you do, but then noticed that it is *clearly and distinctly* written as “***so***” **in italic** to emphasize this specific word.

What does “so”  mean in the above sentence? How does “*so*” here function grammatically?

Logically and empirically, it's hard to believe such a reputed author as Lord Jeffery Archer deiberately put "*so*" in Italic to *show off* his error.

Comment: I am looking at a copy of the book where the sentence says 'I would have to answer yes'. Can you check it's not a typo?

Comment: My search reveals that the word is *to*, not *so*, making the sentence a very understandable "I would have to answer yes". Perhaps you could see if this is a typo?

Comment: predudices  is also misspelled

Comment: @Peter. I reread and checked the line in question on the book at my hand which I bought through Amazon several times by using a magnifying glass. Nevertheless, it was 'flawlessly" spelt as "I would have so answer yes," "so" in Italic, and remains to be 'so.' I wish I can send you a photocopy of the page of the book.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a typo.

Comment: #Yoichi Oishi "I wish I could send you a photocopy of the page in the book."

Comment: @The Beefer Fan. You can send your copy to [yoioishi@ jcom.home.ne.jp] if you wish, and I can take picture of the page of the book (though it's very troublesome work for an 81-year-old digital-illiterate old timer who don't (can't) use even cell-phone) and send it as the attachment to your e-mail address, if you strongly wish. But from answers and comments I've received, it seems there are several versions of print (both hard print and PDF), which include "have so answer' and "have to answer" without the author's endorsement or clarification on this speciffic point.

Comment: @YoichiOishi No my friend Mr Oishi. I corrected your English. You wrote 'I wish I can send you a photocopy of the page of the book' but is situation hypotheticel in present so should use 'could' not 'can'. Ok? I can help you write a good English my buddy. I have got your back so that The Beefer Fan and Mr Oishi can kik an ass in a English Lauguage and a Usage Stack Exchange! You need a help just let me know!

Comment: @The Beefer. True. It has to be "I wish I could send ...." Thank you for your advice. I'll contact you when I need your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a misprint in your edition, Oishi-san. That word should be *to*, and it's an ordinary infinitive. (I'd link to a PDF, but it's a copyright work which the PDF infringes.)

> Perhaps to a limited or ill-informed person I would have to answer yes, but not with any intelligent voter who puts the issues before outdated prejudices

I suspect that it's gone through two misprintings: first from *to* to *so*, and then emphasised as well. *So* can be used as an emphatic: *I would have to so answer yes,* and I guess that the printer italicised it for emphasis to give it this meaning. Unfortunately in doing so he only emphasised the original error.

Interestingly, even in the PDF there is no full-stop after *prejudices*. Perhaps Lord Archer needs a better proof-reader.

Comment: Maybe better a comment?

Comment: Interestingly enough, the "yes" is spelled "yts" in the PDF available on the net. Seems someone scanned and OCRed it

Comment: @medica Indeed. If only comments could use the same formatting :-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - here we disagree. *This is a typo* does not need to be formatted. ')

Comment: One should not really answer in comments. Answers should go in the Your Answer box. If you don't think the question is worthy of an answer, vote to close (if there's a valid close reason). If you don't think the answer is useful, vote down. If it is useful, vote up. Don't vote on an answer based on what you think of the question.

Comment: @medica If an answer/comment/response brings in something valuable, reasonable, and (English) language related, like the reason a link isn't posted, and/or how an error may have evolved (cf tracing elliptical expressions), I'll not invoke the 'isn't a real answer' complaint. I'd not go as far as John Lawler when he says 'There's no difference between 'answers' and 'comments', but I've occasionally used an 'answer' where I'd have wished to use a 'comment' as per regs, but felt the rudimentary formatting available would lead to a lack of clarity.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. I read it as "I would have to answer yes,” as I wrote in my question, but the word, "so" is shown in Italic. Hence, I thought there should be a special reason for the author to have used "so." Though somebody down-voted my question perhaps for the reason of "too obvious" typo, non-native English speakers like me can not judge and declair it's a typo with confidence that the down-voter has. And in Japan, we would require 100 years to discover a typo in the book written by reputed authors and published by reputed publishers. Typo in public literatures is a shame. We never accept

Comment: Cont. a typo as a matter of course as the down-voter takes it for granted. I think it the basic cultural difference from the world the down-voter resides in.

Comment: Until it was determined to be a typo, I thought it was an affected voice of an emphatic young person saying, "I would have *so* answer(ed) yes.", which is a viable possibility to me who is not familiar with the background of the character speaking the line.  I think the downvote is patently unfair in this case.

Comment: @YoichiOishi - I don't know who your downvoter was, but everybody has them. When something makes no sense whatsoever (as typos are wont to do), you can google it by searching a half-dozen words in quotes (I googled "answer yes, but not with any intelligent voter") which appear before or after the mystery word. That is how I found it, and probably a couple of other users did so as well. Cultures are indeed different, but one thing remains constant: where humans are involved, mistakes will be made.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - I agree with you; I thought the error was in answer(ed) which makes sense, although "so answered" should refer to a prior (not following) answer. But my initial search was for a typo in answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - "One should not really answer in comments." Done all the time, esp. in instances like this. "Don't vote on an answer based on what you think of the question." I don't. I know some do, but I don't subscribe to that idea.